# Multidimensional Arrays, Vuex & Mutations

Tags: arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, vuex, mutation

I'm attempting to both add and remove items in a multidimensional array stored in Vuex.

The array is a group of categories, and each category and have a sub-category (infinity,  not simply a two dimensional array).

Example data set is something like this:

```
[
   {
     id: 123,
     name: 'technology',
     parent_id: null,
     children: [
          id: 456,
          name: 'languages',
          parent_id: 123,
          children: [
             {
                id:789,
                name: 'javascript',
                parent_id: 456
             }, {
                id:987,
                name: 'php',
                parent_id: 456
             }
          ]
        }, {
          id: 333,
          name: 'frameworks', 
          parent_id 123,
          children: [
             {
                id:777,
                name: 'quasar',
                parent_id: 333
             }
          ]
        }
     ]
   }
]
```

....my question is, how do I best add and remove elements to this array, which is inside of a Vuex Store?

I normally manipulate simple arrays inside the Vuex Store using Vue.Set() to get reactivity. However, because I'm not sure how deep the nested array being manipulated is - I simply can't figure it out.

Here's an example of how I thought I could add a sub-category element using recursion:

```
export const append = (state, item) => {
  if (item.parent_uid !== null) {
    var categories = []
    state.data.filter(function f (o) {
      if (o.uid === item.parent_uid) {
        console.log('found it')
        o.push(item)
        return o
      }
      if (o.children) {
        return (o.children = o.children.filter(f)).length
      }
    })
  } else {
    state.data.push(item)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that `vuex`, or any other state management library based on `flux` architecture, isn't designed to handle nested object graph, let alone arbitrary/infinity nested objects that you mentioned. To make the matter worse, even with shallow state object, `vuex` works best when you [define the shape of the state (all desired fields) upfront](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules).

IMHO, there are two possible approaches you can take

#### 1. Normalize your data

This is an approach recommended by vue.js team member [here][2].

If you really want to retain information about the hierarchical structure after normalization, you can use [flat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat) in conjunction with a transformation function to flatten your nested object by `name` to something like this:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  ...
  state: {
    data: {
      'technology':                      { id: 123, name: 'technology', parent_id: null },
      'technology.languages':            { id: 456, name: 'languages', parent_id: 123 },
      'technology.languages.javascript': { id: 789, name: 'javascript', parent_id: 456 },
      'technology.languages.php':        { id: 987, name: 'php', parent_id: 456 },
      'technology.frameworks':           { id: 333, name: 'frameworks', parent_id: 123 },
      'technology.frameworks.quasar':    { id: 777, name: 'quasar', parent_id: 333 },
    }
  },
});
```

Then you can use `Vue.set()` on each item in `state.data` as usual.

#### 2. Make a totally new state object on modification

This is the second approach mentioned in [`vuex`'s documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules):

> When adding new properties to an Object, you should either:
>
> - Use `Vue.set(obj, 'newProp', 123)`, or
> - Replace that Object with a fresh one
>
> ...

You can easily achieve this with another library: [object-path-immutable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-path-immutable). For example, suppose you want to add new category under `languages`, you can create a mutation like this:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  mutations: {
    addCategory(state, { name, id, parent_id }) {
      state.data = immutable.push(state.data, '0.children.0.children', { id, name, parent_id });
    },
  },
  ...
});
```

By reassigning `state.data` to a new object each time a modification is made, `vuex` reactivity system will be properly informed of changes you made to `state.data`. This approach is desirable if you don't want to normalize/denormalize your data.

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer, it's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @muffinlab Glad it helps. :)